# Drupal 7 - Couple theming questions

Tags: php, image, templates, drupal

Hi i got couple questions.

1) I want to set one block template for couple blocks positions (via template.php).

2) Same as first but with page template for couple url names and types (via template.php).

3) I got image field. Instead of showing all pictures on full view, i want to display one image which i can choose via pager (for example < 1 2 3 4 >).

4) I want to add images and add redirection for every of them, is this possible?

Thank you for answers and sorry for my english.

Comment: I would suggest you split this up into multiple questions, and also show that you have put some effort into solving it yourself. Eg what have you tried, what you are stuggling with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use the HOOK_theme() function for theming a custom block. Otherwise you can write a block--BLOCKID.tpl.php for theming a drupal block (title + body)
(https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)

2) Same answer as 1)

3) You have to use the HOOK_pager() (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7)

4) I do not understand what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it out. In 4 - for example i got image field, when i add a picture, i want option to make this picture redirect to some site: EXAMPLE - I got page named redirects, i added facebook logo and when someone clicks it i want this logo to redirect to facebook.com. Now you understand?

Comment: Personnaly, i had social link not editable directly in templates

Comment: Nevermind about 3 and 4, i installed field slideshow and link image field.